# What to do with 16.04 Questions?

Tags: discussion

With the amount of questions growing as the 16.04 is flying towards its release day, what is the correct way to deal with the high rising # of questions that are [currently posted](https://askubuntu.com/searchhttps://askubuntu.com/search?tab=newest&q=16.04) and the questions that are going to (guessing) flood the server as it gets closer?

Would answering the questions in the beat way with a warning be appropriate?example:

```
16.04 release day is not tell April and any information in this post may not be vaild or work.
```

Or should we continue falging them as off topic?